# Javadoc not rendering custom tag in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I have a custom Javadoc tag @date in my code, and I can see it in the regular view like this:

```
/**
 * @author kira
 * @date 2022/1/19
 */
```

but after I render Javadocs, it becomes like this:

```
Author: kira
```

the @date tag is missing, how can I make the custom tag appear in the rendered view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known limitation. Feel free to vote/comment for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200852 .